# Bulk insert using code first migrations for azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

We have a lot of data that needs to be loaded into a number of tables. As far as I can see we have two options:

1. Include the data as part of the Configuration class seed method 
   Problems
   1.a. this would be slow and involve writing a lot of C# code)
2. Use bulk insert with code first migrations - a lot quicker and probably a better solution. 
   Problems
   2.a. It may prove tricky working with other data that gets loaded into the same tables as part of the seed. 
   2.b. It requires SQL Identity Insert to be switched on.

What solution is best and if it is 2 how do I go about bulk insert with code first migrations and how can I address the problems?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?  Azure Sql restricts inserts to only 1k rows per INSERT statement.  just another thing to consider when chosing

Comment: I can't find a decent solution Scott, struggling with this one. Any ideas?

Comment: I personally would get the tables designed correctly (make sure identity seeds are correct) , make sure all that is good then migrate straight into the database.  If coming from another Sql database you're good to go.  If you have another type of database still easy using Sql Management Studio directly

Comment: another thing , if the data is from another SQL database , just create a data-only script .  The good side to this is there will be one insert per statement. So it will generate s many as needed and you won't get into those stupid limits Azure gives you

Answer (score 0):

Bypassing EF and using ADO.NET/SQL is definitely a good approach for bulk data upload. The best approach depends on whether you want the data to be inserted as part of migration or just logic that runs on app start.

- If you want it to be inserted as part of a migration (which may be nice since then you don't have to worry about defensive checks if the data exists etc.) then you can use the `Sql(string)` method to execute sql that uses whatever format and sql features you want (including switching IDENTITY_INSERT on/off). In EF6.1 there is also an overload that allows you to easily run a .sql file rather than having everything in code as a string.
- If you want to do it on app start, then just create an instance of your context and then access `Database.Connection` to get the raw SqlConnection and use ADO.NET directly to insert the data.